# Correct way to change <xacro:arg name> in launch file

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with Husky in melodic (i.e. ubuntu 18.04). The laser option is disabled by default as shown below

```
<xacro:arg name="laser_enabled" default="$(optenv HUSKY_LMS1XX_ENABLED 0)" />
```

When I  start the launch file as follows

```
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch laser_enabled:=true
```

It doesn't change anything. What is the correct way to change this option? My current solution is to open the file as admin and change `0` to `1`. This does slove the problem but it is not an optimal solution. Any suggestions!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400658/correct-way-to-change-%3Cxacro:arg-name%3E-in-launch-file/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2022-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use Environment Variables for this:

http://wiki.ros.org/husky_bringup/Tutorials/Customize%20Husky%20Configuration

```
 HUSKY_LMS1XX_ENABLED    false    Enable/disable the SICK LMS1XX LIDAR
```

====

Maybe connected:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/341246/xacro-arg-not-working-in-lauch-file/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/38956/pass-parameters-to-xacro-in-launch-file/
- http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Rospack_commands

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-15**:
what is the actual command that I need to type in the terminal to change these environment variables?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-15**:
To set an environment variable the export command is used. You give the variable a name, which is what is used to access it in shell scripts and configurations and then a value to hold whatever data is needed in the variable, e.g. `export NAME=VALUE`, so there it would be `export HUSKY_LMS1XX_ENABLED=true`

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-16**:
I've tried this but it is not working.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-16**:
Please add more details in the edit of your questions, maybe something there is incorrect.
Do you call other launchers inside this one?

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-16**:
^never mind, it worked. thank you.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-16**:
Relevant issue with similar problem: https://github.com/husky/husky/issues/155

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-16**:
If it worked, please accept the answer so it will be marked in the questions queue :)